# Переменные окружения и получение имени исполняемого файла в Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, c++, apple

При разработке под MAC OS X на языке С/С++ столкнулась с проблемой: как задать переменную окружения, если в Windows достаточно было прописать `%APPDATA%` или `%HOMEPATH%`, а в MAC OS такой номер не пройдёт. Допустим, хочу прописать через переменную окружения адрес:

```
/Users/user-name/Folder
```

Вот так не работает:

```
/~/Folder
```

И ещё вопрос. В Windows можно получить адрес текущего исполняемого файла с помощью **GetModuleFileName()**. Подскажите, пожалуйста, аналог этой функции в MAC OS, желательно с примером использования. Или, к примеру, есть ли такая функция, которая на вход принимает имя искомого файла, а возвращает его местоположение на компьютере, если таковой есть, или если их несколько, какой-нибудь массив или структуру с их местоположением.

Спасибо за внимание, надеюсь на вашу помощь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, что вы имеете в виду под «заданием» переменной окружения. В Си/С++ можно использовать [`setenv()` и `getenv()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/getenv.3.html) — посмотрите, вдруг это то, что вам нужно.

---

Получить имя текущей программы (~ *имя файла*), можно, используя [`_NSGetExecutablePath()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dyld.3.html), через `argv[0]` (доступ к которому можно получить [не только в `main()`](http://unixjunkie.blogspot.ru/2006/07/access-argc-and-argv-from-anywhere.html)) или при помощи [`proc_pidpath()`](https://astojanov.wordpress.com/2011/11/16/mac-os-x-resolve-absolute-path-using-process-pid/).

Пример использования связки `_NSGetExecutablePath()` + `realpath()`:

```
// $ clang demo.c -o demo
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // realpath()
#include <limits.h> // PATH_MAX
#include <mach-o/dyld.h> // _NSGetExecutablePath()

int main(void)
{
    char path[PATH_MAX];
    uint32_t size = sizeof(path);
    if (_NSGetExecutablePath(path, &size) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Buffer is too small to store the whole path string"
                        "needs %u bytes\n", size);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    } 
    // path => ./demo
    char *resolved = realpath(path, NULL);
    // resolved => /Users/anon/something/onemorelevel/demo
    fprintf(stdout, "Executable path: %s\n", resolved);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

---

P.S. *Лучше бы вы всё же разбили этот вопрос на два.*

Comment: @VioLet, спасибо за ответ! Посмотрела функции setenv() и getenv(), это то, что нужно, но почему-то getenv() всегда возвращает nil((( Пробовала уже разные переменные окружения передавать в функцию, всё тщетно. Нашла команду, как в терминале MAC OS посмотреть список доступных переменных окружения: printenv, но функция их не находит(((

Comment: @Kristya очень странно. По крайней мере у меня код ниже работает (печатает путь к домашней папке текущего пользователя):  

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    
    int main (int argc, char* argv[])
    {
     fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", getenv("HOME"));
        return 0;
    }

Comment: @Kristya а если в терминале выполнить команду `env`, в списке переменных отображается тот же "HOME"?  
Расскажите ещё про вашу IDE — возможно она запускает вашу программу особым образом, переопределяя стандартные переменные среды.

Comment: @VioLet, у меня AppCode. Вот что интересное выявила: в командную строку функция выводит путь, а в переменную не сохраняет и всё!  

Вот такой код не работает:  

    int main (int argc, char* argv[])
    {
        char *path;
        path = getenv("HOME");
        if (path == NULL)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
  
Пишет ошибку: "Error: Is a directory".  
А в списке переменных окружениыя есть "HOME", когда смотрю в терминеале.

Comment: Правда в том, что как оказалось, эта функция не отработает в AppCode в режиме отладки. А вот если сделать запуск БЕЗ ОТЛАДКИ, она работает. Как вообще можно так писать среду?!

Comment: @Kristya думаю, в этом есть своя логика: в режиме отладки, вы, как правило, указываете все переменные среды самостоятельно, и ваша программа использует именно их (это часто бывает нужно для тестирования, а ведь для него и существует режим отладки). В то же время при релизной сборке и запуске программа будет использовать системные переменные.

Comment: @VioLet, подскажите пожалуйста ещё такую вещь: realpath будет преобразовывать адрес, который пока не создан? Например, я хочу скопировать файл в /Users/user-name/MyApp.app, но MyApp.app ещё не лежит в папке /user-name. И нужно ли вообще к такому адресу применять realpath()???

Comment: @Kristya а зачем вам применять `realpath()`, если у вас уже и так полный путь?  

`realpath()` делает исключительно следующее:  

> The realpath() function resolves all symbolic links, extra ``/'' characters, and
     references to /./ and /../ in file_name.  

ну а так как в пути, который вы привели, нет ни символьных ссылок, ни "../' или "./", то и `realpath()` вам не нужен.